# How to edit inner value of XElement

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I'm stuck on a dumb case..

I have an XML like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
 <Identity="title" text2="text" text3="text" />
 <Node1>        
  <Name>bob</Name>
  <Age>30</Age>
  <Image>img.png</Image>
  <Country>blabla</Country>
 </Node1>
 <Node2>
  <Elem1>6.2</Elem1>
  <Elem1>6.2</Elem1>
 </Node2>
 <Node3>
  <Elem1>6.2</Elem1>
  <Elem1>6.2</Elem1>
 </Node3>
 ...
```

I want to edit the value of Name (bob) inside Node1.

So I isolated Node1 data in using:

```
var name = xml.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName.Equals("Node1")).Single();
```

But I'm stuck on assigning a new value, this line gets a null exception.

```
name.Element("Name").Value = "dude";
```

I tried other stuff like

```
var name = xml.Elements("Package").Elements("Node1").Single().Parent.Element("Name");
    name.Value = "dude";
```

But it's not working either (System.InvalidOperationException)

Can someone help me please ? :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use the code `xml.Element("Package").Element("Node1").Element("Name").Value = "dude";`, it works as expected: it sets the value `"dude"`. As you can see, it is also much simpler than your approach, since it doesn't use `.Single().Parent` or `.Where()`

By the way: `<Identity="title" text2="text" text3="text" />` is invalid XML.

The issues are caused by the namespace. You can remove a namespace attribute from an `XElement` with this code:

```
public static void RemoveNamespace(this XElement element)
{
    element.Attributes().Where(x => x.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove();
    element.Name = element.Name.LocalName;
}
```

In your case this would work:

```
var name = xml.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName.Equals("Node1")).Single();
name.Elements().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName.Equals("Name")).FirstOrDefault().RemoveNamespace();
name.Element("Name").Value = "dude";
```